# Azure storage locality

Tags: azure, storage, scale

I am somewhat confused by azure storage account, I do not understand why a storage account can’t have multiple geo-locations, and then why a request can’t be automatically handled by a geo-local azure storage.

To make it clear, consider below:

I have two data centers, West-US , East-Europe, each have web-servers and blob storages, web-server is stateless.

For example:

- Region West-US : webserver 1,  Blob1
- Region East-Europe : webserver2, Blob2

I want my East-Europe web-server2 to access “Region East-Europe blob2” and West-US web-server1 to access “Region West-US bolo1”, due to geo-locaity.
I do not want webserver1 to access Blob2 because extra latency unless Blob1 is inaccessible.

But Blob1 and Blob2 are in different region and so they have different URLs and Access Keys, I do not see an easy way to archive what I want.
I know there is azure traffic manager, but looks like it only support “Cloud Service” and “WebSites”, not to mention there is also the ACCESS KEY.

So, my question, am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2013/12/04/introducing-read-access-geo-replicated-storage-ra-grs-for-windows-azure-storage.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Blobs are accessible via REST API's - so it should not matter where your webserver is you can reference the dependent blobs using the appropriate blob's URI. One thing you do of course have to do is ensure the blob is actually publically accessible. Take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.blobcontainerpublicaccesstype.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Of course they will have different URLs and Access keys and you should use separate code base in web server 1 and web server 2 to access these two blobs differently.

A completely different thing is Azure CDN. I'm talking about this, because you were referring to a traffic manager kind of a mechanism for Azure storage. CDN is not exactly that, but it certainly strikes mind as it might be relevant for you.

You can make these blobs as the source to the CDN and CDN will cache these contents at different edge servers. In your web application, instead of directly accessing the web URL, you can access the CDN URL and CDN will decide from which edge server the requested content (blob) should be served from.

Take a look at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/cdn-serve-content-from-cdn-in-your-web-application/